# hql-query to a child entity in bidirectional associations

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Confronted with the problem -

```
////////////////// GbCapacityEntity class //////////////////
@Entity
@Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONE)
@Table(name = "MARKSIST.GB_CAPACITY")
public class GbCapacityEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORG_ID")
    private Integer orgId;
...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="gbCapacityEntity")
    private List<GbLoadForecast> gbLoadForecast;
    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public List<GbLoadForecast> getGbLoadForecast() {
        return gbLoadForecast;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param gbLoadForecast
     */
    public void setGbLoadForecast(List<GbLoadForecast> gbLoadForecast) {
        this.gbLoadForecast = gbLoadForecast;
    }



////////////////// GbLoadForecast class ////////////////// 
@Entity
@Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONE)
@Table(name = "MARKSIST.GB_LOAD_FORECAST")
public class GbLoadForecast {
    @Id 
    @Column(name = "ORG_ID")
    private Integer orgId;
...
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private GbCapacityEntity gbCapacityEntity;
    /**
     * @return
     */
    public GbCapacityEntity getGbCapacityEntity() {
        return gbCapacityEntity;
    }
    /**
     * @param gbLoadForecast
     */
    public void setGbCapacityEntity(GbCapacityEntity gbCapacityEntity) {
        this.gbCapacityEntity = gbCapacityEntity;
    }
...

////////////////// Some query //////////////////  

        String hql = "FROM com.intellex.marksist.hbn.model.GbLoadForecast E " +
                     "WHERE E.orgId = :id1 AND E.cargoGroup = :id2";

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getMarksistSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("id1", orgId);
        query.setParameter("id2", gcId);
        List results = query.list();
        session.close();
...
```

On the instructions **query.list();** thrown exception -
**[java] 4085 ["http-apr-8080"-exec-10] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-00904: "GBLOADFORE0_"."GBCAPACITYENTITY_ORG_ID": ???????????? ?????????????**

Anybody know why? I would be very grateful! : -)

=========================================

Added @ JoinColumn annotation in the child class, and now it looks like this -

```
////////////////// GbLoadForecast class ////////////////// 
@Entity
@Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONE)
@Table(name = "MARKSIST.GB_LOAD_FORECAST")
public class GbLoadForecast {
    @Id 
    @Column(name = "ORG_ID")
    private Integer orgId;
...
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORG_ID")
    private GbCapacityEntity gbCapacityEntity;
    /**
     * @return
     */
    public GbCapacityEntity getGbCapacityEntity() {
        return gbCapacityEntity;
    }
    /**
     * @param gbLoadForecast
     */
    public void setGbCapacityEntity(GbCapacityEntity gbCapacityEntity) {
        this.gbCapacityEntity = gbCapacityEntity;
    }
...
```

But now another exception - Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.intellex.marksist.hbn.model.GbLoadForecast column: ORG_ID (should be mapped with insert = "false" update = "false" )

The thing is, i suspect that there are a bunch of the same name of the field-name ORG_ID column is as in table MARKSIST.GB_LOAD_FORECAST, and in the table MARKSIST.GB_CAPACITY. Or is not it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine this mapping:

```
@Id 
@Column(name = "ORG_ID")
private Integer orgId;
...
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORG_ID")
private GbCapacityEntity gbCapacityEntity;
```

This means that the ID is mapped to the column `ORG_ID`, and that you also have a column, which is a foreign key to the GB_CAPACITY.ORG_ID column, and which is also named `ORG_ID`.

You can't have two columns with the same name in the same table. Choose a different name for your join column:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "ORG_ID_OF_CAPACITY")
```